# PlotLegends` and VectorAnalysis is now obsolete on Mathematica v 12.0.0.0 Home edition

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, vector-calculus

My code was working a few months ago. Now I receive the messages:

```
General::obspkg: PlotLegends` is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.
```

and

```
General::obspkg: VectorAnalysis is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.
```

For this code see [here](https://github.com/bjdarrer/particle_in_gradient_slope50_bjd_23rdJune2023_2c/blob/main/particle_in_gradient_slope50_bjd_23rdJune2023_2c.nb#L327).

Can someone help solve this issue?

Comment: (1) Does it still work? "May conflict" also means it might not. (2) The compatibility guide is here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/PlotLegends.html

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It runs the code but produces no video plot file. I get messages: `General::obspkg: PlotLegends is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.` and `General::obspkg: VectorAnalysis is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.`

Comment: To start, delete `Needs["PlotLegends\`"]` and change all instances of `PlotLegend -> ` to `PlotLegends ->`. For any other issues, see the documentation for [` PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html)

Comment: The compatibility guide for upgrading from VectorAnalysis is here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/VectorAnalysis.html -- I have no idea how to determine why it worked before and does not now. Perhaps you changed versions of Mathematica, but I figure you already considered that.

Comment: No, I didn't change versions of Mathematica.

Comment: The comment by @Bob Hanlon, seems to have resolved the `PlotLegends` issue, I am also checking chatGPT-3.5 for help on `VectorAnalysis`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the new differential operators are the missing coordinates

```
     Grad[pGb[x, t], < missing coordinates > ], ddt pXb -> D[pXb[x, t], t], 
     laplacian pXb -> Laplacian[pXb[x, t], < missing coordinates > ]
```

set at the start by the now obsolete Coordinates statement.